# XML mapping to salesforce using Dataweave

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

I am trying to map the data from xml (input file) to developer salesforce version.

***input file:***

```
<Z0DEBMAS>    
    <E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">    
    <KUNNR>0030003926</KUNNR>    
    <NAME1>SAMS CLUB #6493</NAME1>    
    <VKORG>4571</VKORG>    
    </E1KNA1M>       
</Z0DEBMAS>
```

***Dataweave Code in Mule:***

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform XML to sfdc">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.Z0DEBMAS.*E1KNA1M map {
    AccountNumber: $.KUNNR,
    Name: $.NAME1,
    Sales_Organization__c: $.VKORG
    }]]></dw:set-payload>    
</dw:transform-message>
```

**I am getting output for only the entry KUNNR and NAME1 but not for VKORG**, I am getting null values for VKORG as shown below.

***Output in Mule Console:***

```
INFO  2016-08-25 12:30:06,169 [[xmltosfdc_realtime].xmltosfdc_realtimeFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: **[{AccountNumber=0030003926, Name=SAMS CLUB #6493, *Sales_Organization__c=null*}]**
INFO  2016-08-25 12:30:09,467 [[xmltosfdc_realtime].xmltosfdc_realtimeFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [[SaveResult  errors='{[0]}'
 id='0012800000poeQRAAY'
 success='true'
```

[image: Output in salesforce]

Below are  the datatype of the fields to be mapped in salesforce :

[image: datatype]

Please let me know if anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the *Sales Organization* was not mapped due to different data type. If refer to the expected [datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3VLa.png), it should be a Number/Numeric.

Incorrectly, the result of your transformation from DataWeave is a String. Therefore, I suggest you to convert it to Number first e.g.: `Sales_Organization__c: $.VKORG as :number` as Integer or `Sales_Organization__c: $.VKORG as :number {class: "java.math.BigDecimal"}` as BigDecimal

[image]